# array_replace_recursive keep values as keys with null values

Tags: php

I use this function like you'd use angular.extend() or $.extend() in my controllers.

```
function extend($base = array(), $replacements = array())
{
    $base = !is_array($base) ? array() : $base;
    $replacements = !is_array($replacements) ? array() : $replacements;

    return array_replace_recursive($base, $replacements);
}
```

Standard use:

```
$inputs = extend([
  'name' => 'test',
  'empty'
], getInputs());
// getInputs() grabs the data from a form encoded or json body request.
```

I want `empty` to be a key so I can use this array with Laravel models or other objects later on.

I get:

```
[
  [name] => 'test',
  [0] => 'empty'
]
```

I want:

```
[
  [name] => 'test',
  [empty] => null
]
```

This should output: **OK (1 test, 2 assertions)**

```
public function testInputs()
{
    $inputs = \Api::inputs([
        'name' => 'test',
        'empty'
    ]);

    $this->assertArrayHasKey('name', $inputs);
    $this->assertArrayHasKey('empty', $inputs);
}
```

Is there a native way to do this or will I be rolling my own?

Comment: but `empty` is a value in your input array. You expect that function to change it to a key?

Comment: @onetrickpony I just clarified my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, non-associative elements in arrays are treated as values for an associative array with automatic integer keys. [The documentation](http://www.php.net/array) states:

> The key is optional. If it is not specified, PHP will use the
>   increment of the largest previously used integer key.

What that means is that `['abc', 'def']` is the same as `[0 => 'abc', 1 => 'def']`.

If you want your function to use values as keys, there is no way you will be able to differentiate an array that actually uses integers for keys from those that PHP automatically assigned due to missing keys.

I personally believe it is easier just to change the input to the function so that it is in the right format: `['name' => 'test', 'empty' => null]`.

If that is not an option and you **know the values you receive will never have numbers as keys** you need to change your function to something like the following:

```
function extend($base, $replacements) {
    $base = !is_array($base) ? array() : $base;
    $replacements = !is_array($replacements) ? array() : $replacements;

    $ret = array();
    foreach ($base as $key => $val) {
        if (is_int($key)) { // value without key
            $ret[$val] = null;
        } else {
            $ret[$key] = $val;
        }
    }

    return array_replace_recursive($ret, $replacements);        
}
```